# Designing an "Events" Table with Multiple Table References in a Data Model

Tags: database, data-modeling, theory

Although the original problem was presented to me as an MSSQL database implementation, what I'm discussing here is a general perspective, not specific details.

Let's consider that I have three base tables:

1. **Drivers**
2. **Vehicles**
3. **TransportCompanies**

Each of these tables has its own primary key and a set of fields unique to them. For example, the **Drivers** table contains attributes like `Name`, `Address`, `BirthDate`, and more, while the **Vehicles** table includes attributes such as `LicensePlate`, `VehicleType`, `Brand`, `Model`, and so on.

Now, there's a new requirement to implement an **Events** table. The goal is to store all events in a single table (as an arbitrary prerequisite, I suppose), given that the events share many common attributes such as `Type` (Unavailable, On Hold, Accident, Priority Request), `DateTime from/to`, `Flags` to determine if the event has a monetary cost associated with it, the Company `personnel` responsible for tracking or resolving it, and more.

I see two primary options for designing this:

1. The **Events** table can have three nullable fields that serve as foreign keys pointing to each individual table (i.e., **Drivers**, **Vehicles**, and **TransportCompanies**), along with a separate field (let's call it `EventType`) that identifies to which of the three related tables a specific Event record applies. Validation can be enforced with a trigger to ensure that one of the three foreign keys has a not NULL value and that it matches the one specified in `EventType`.
2. Alternatively, they could unify the three different tables into one **Entities** table, which has a unique primary key, a field identifying the `EntityType` (Driver, Vehicle, Company, etc.), and all the fields from the current 3 tables (Some fields like `Name` could be unified, but most wont). The `EntityType` field would be a foreign key to an **EntityType** table, providing flexibility for potential future Types. In this case, the **Events** table is simplified, as it only needs the `EntityID` foreign key pointing to the **Entities** table.

There could be a third option as well: maintaining separate **Event** tables for each of the **Drivers**, **Vehicles**, and **TransportCompanies**.

Of course, I'm simplifying the scenario, and it's worth noting that this is a legacy database where the **Driver**, **Vehicle**, and **Company** tables already exist as separate entities.

To reiterate, I'm not seeking the best solution for this specific case but rather exploring the ideal way to model this if there were no constraints and the database could be designed from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

That "events share many common attributes" is not a valid reason to store them in a single table.  They are conceptually different entities and each relates to a different main entity.  They should be modeled as separate tables, and allowed to evolve independently.

Also it's often most efficient to store such "weak entities" with a primary key of (DriverId,DriverEventId), which in a BTree will optimize storage and access of the events for a particular DriverId.

Comment: Part of the request is to visualize all the events together. Should I make a view with union all the different events tables? Or steer them away from that requirement?

Comment: You could create a view with UNION ALL (not just UNION since the events are guaranteed unique), or have a batch job that creates a reporting table, or just run 3 queries from the visualization layer.  In any case visualization requirements don't need to dictate the data model.